# Is there any rate-limit for graphql on dotnet?

Tags: .net-core, graphql, rate-limiting

'https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit'
The package can be set rate limit according to the endpoint of RestApi. Is there a package that can set rate limit according to graphql resolver?